# Converting numbers to ADN structures in C++

Tags: c++

A little bit of background: I am fairly new to C++ as I began to code just 2 years ago. My teacher (I am in high school) gave me an interesting idea for my final project and I don't know where to start. She told me to make a program that would convert decimal numbers to ADN structures given the following:

```
'A'=0
'C'=1
'G'=2
'T'=-1
```

I have done conversions from base 10 to base 2 and base 4, but I don't see how to use that -1, since in base 4 the remainder would be from 0 to 3.

Can anyone please help me with an idea?

Comment: I didn't get what numbers you are converting. Can you show us some code?

Comment: You should also provide a sample of your code. There are variable types that consider the sign.

Comment: ACGT sounds much like genetics. "ADN structure" sounds like DNA structures in French, after I googled it. Converting decimal numbers to something with 0, 1, 2 and -1 sounds like a conversion to mixed base, nothing to do with genetics. Knuth discussed mixed base conversion in The Art of Computer Programming. But there is apparently no connection from your decimal numbers to DNA sequences. If that connection is what you're asking about, you'd better ask your teacher!